# django add user 404 error but refresh page ok

Tags: python, django

When I use add user in django admin site, after I click save, I got the error

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://192.168.11.20:8888/admin/auth/user/5/

user object with primary key u'5' does not exist.
```

but when I refresh the page, it's gave me the right page with the same link...and it shows that I have already created the user, how could this happen?

Comment: Have you removed the admin.autodiscover() from urls.py?

Comment: @DaneoShiga Nope, I just deploy the site on a virtual machine, when I run it in my local environment, it's ok